# A question on maximal subgroups of a finite group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $K$ be a finite non-Abelian simple group , $G=K\times K$ ,  and  $H=\{(x,x)\in G\big|x\in K\}$.

Question:

Is $H$ a maximal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: What have you tried?  You also likely mean maximal and not maximum (maximal means that there is nothing larger whereas maximum means that it contains all subgroups).

Comment: See if you can a subgroup $H'$ of $G$ with $H\subsetneq H'\subsetneq G$. If you can, there's your answer. If you can't, can you prove that non exist?

Comment: Note that any subgroup of $G$ containing $H$ is a congruence (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation) of $K$. Then use the fact that for groups congruences are in bijection with normal subgroups.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H'$ be a subgroup of $G$ strictly containing $H$. Show that the set $K'\subseteq K$ defined by the $x\in K$ such that $(x, e)\in H'$ is a normal, non-trivial subgroup of $K$. Here are hints for each of the three properties I mentioned:

Subgroup: Use that $H'$ is a subgroup of $G$, along with the definition of $K'$

Non-trivial: Because $H'$ *strictly* contains $H$, it contains at least one $(x, y)$ with $x, y\in K, x\neq y$. Now multiply that element with $(y^{-1}, y^{-1})$

Normality: If $x\in K'$, and $y\in K$, then $(y, y),(x, e)$ and $(y^{-1}, y^{-1})$ are all elements of $H'$